# angularjs directive: how to check for transcluded content

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to create an AngularJS directive that:

1. wraps arbitrary content and
2. inserts placeholder content if transcluded content is not provided

...but cannot figure out a way to check for existence of transcluded content in directive.

[Here's a plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/XrvXUoCZCEHjzCeMpcBU) - help ;-

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will for sure work for you: [PLNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/ST22AlaXnX7PMuIqsePp?p=preview).

Basically what happens there: in `transclusionFn` you have possibility to interfere with the clone of transcluded content.

Comment: thanks! FWIW, I forked your fork to have transcluded content presence toggle an attribute used to ng-show placeholder content: [plnkr2](http://plnkr.co/edit/6kXPabPUo1f0KIY2E9Cm?p=preview). appreciate your help

Comment: Why did you put `elementRef = element;` on line 17?